# How to listen to smart contract events using nodejs server?

Tags: contract-development, javascript, events, nodejs

I am currently trying to '**listen events**' emitted from my smart contract. I am able to run my scripts created by using the `node` command and it works as intended, and I want to host it on a server. I have a few questions about how to host it on a server:

> What is the proper way to invoke the function that creates listeners?

Currently I am implementing this method:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if (!on) {
    on = true;
    main();
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Setup the listeners" });
  } else {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Already operating" });
  }
});
```

By calling '**main**', I am setting up the listeners as such:

```
 const contract = new ethers.Contract(marketAddress, ABI, provider);
  console.log("Listening");

  contract.on("NewListing", async (listingId, event) => {...}
```

I would like to know the correct way to **setup** the listeners, to send a get request to the server, including if the server went to sleep.

> Is there any free server hosting platforms that would keep the websocket connection open (or what would be my best bet to maintain the connection)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have some alternatives, we can write the API that will serve as a layer between our frontend application and our **smart contract**, currently there are a **subscription method** to do that with `web3.js`.

> But remember that you need a web-socket endpoint to use subscriptions in web3.js

Inside your project folder, create files `routes.js`, `server.js`, and `config.js`.

> **server.js** is the main file that runs as Node.js server. We are requiring all of the dependencies at the beginning of the file, using **cors** and **Express**, we can check for Web3.js and make it interact with blockchain network by providing a localhost address.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const routes = require('./routes');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const contract = require('@truffle/contract');
const artifacts = require('./build/contracts/Contacts.json');
const CONTACT_ABI = require('./config');
const CONTACT_ADDRESS = require('./config');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); 
} else {
```

> This is an example connecting to a **MongoDB** ready to use in the future, so inside the callback function of the **mongodb.connect()**, we connect with **Cluster0** and getting accounts from the Ethereum blockchain network.

Using the 'web3 Contract function', open the **config.js** file where we pass *CONTACT_ABI* and *CONTACT_ADDRESS* we have connected with the smart contract.

```js
const CONTACT_ADDRESS = '0xB7fC6C3DFebD24EAe16E307Ea39EdF7c93ff7866';

const CONTACT_ABI = [
        {
    "inputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "constructor"
  },
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "contacts",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "id",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "string",
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "string",
        "name": "phone",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function",
    "constant": true
  },
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "count",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function",
    "constant": true
  },
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "string",
        "name": "_name",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "internalType": "string",
        "name": "_phone",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "name": "createContact",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  }
];

module.exports = {
        CONTACT_ABI,
        CONTACT_ADDRESS,
};
```

Then we will call ***routes()*** with all the parameters, creating this routes function in **routes.js** to listen the app on 'port 3000'.

```js
function routes(app, db, accounts, contactList) {
        app.get('/contacts', async (request, response) => {
                let cache = [];
                const COUNTER = await contactList.methods.count().call();

                for (let i = 1; i <= COUNTER; i++) {
      const contact = await contactList.methods.contacts(i).call();
      cache = [...cache, contact];
    }

    response.json(cache);
  });
}

module.exports = routes
```

> We loop through all the *COUNTER* and get contacts one-by-one from **contactList**, which we place in the `cache` variable and finally send to the frontend in response.

Run the server which is now ready to receive requests from **React app**.

```
$ nodemon server.js
```

You can find more based in the [web3.eth.contract](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) official documentation and [web3.eth.accounts](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-accounts.html), including this related post using '[Chainlink](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135301/listen-for-all-the-events-of-a-smart-contract-with-ethers-js-polygon)' or **Polygon** as another option.